# C programming: struct of complex numbers

Tags: c

I have an array of complex numbers and want to add a new complex number at the very first postion of the array.

I have a struct and a function which enters a new complex number at the first position of the array.

I have a struct which holds complex numbers

```
struct Complex
{
  float imag;
  float real;
};
```

I also have a function which is creating an instance of such a complex number on the heap

```
struct Complex* instanceOfComplex(float a, float b)
{
  struct Complex* complex = malloc(sizeof(struct Complex));
  if(complex == NULL)
  {
    return NULL; // out of memory
  }

  complex->imag = a;
  complex->real = b;

  return complex;
}
```

Finally I have a function which should place a new complex number at the very first position of an array of complex numbers

```
int attach(struct Complex *complexArray, struct Complex complex, int length)
{
  int i;
  for(i = length; length > 0; i--)
  {
    complexArray[i] = complexArray[i - 1];
  }
  complexArray[i] = complex;

  length++;

  return length;
}
```

The main function looks like this

```
int main()
{
  float a = 3.6;
  float b = 6.8;

  struct Complex* complex = instanceOfComplex(a, b);

  printf("%f %f\n", complex->imag, complex->real);

  int length = 4;

  struct Complex* complexArray = malloc(sizeof(length + 1) * sizeof(struct Complex));

  complexArray[0] = *instanceOfComplex(8.2, 9.3);
  complexArray[1] = *instanceOfComplex(7.1, 4.6);
  complexArray[2] = *instanceOfComplex(0.1, 2.7);
  complexArray[3] = *instanceOfComplex(5.6, 1.9);

  attach(complexArray, *complex, length);
}
```

So finally the array should contain 5 elements of complex numbers where the new complex number is at position complexArray[0] and the other 4 elements are the following elements.

The problem is in the main function because all elements are holding (8.2, 9.3). Could someone please tell me, whats wrong here?

Comment: `sizeof (length + 1)` is the same as `sizeof (length * 2)` is the same as `sizeof (length - length)` ...

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Notice that C11 knows about complex numbers, read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) §6.2.5-11

Comment: Since you're (apparently) using C99 (or more recent), consider using the *brand new* [`_Complex` types](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.2.5p11)

Comment: also be aware of memory leaks : the memory allocated inside `instanceOfComplex` can not be free'd any more in several instances in your code, since you don't store the returned pointer anywhere, but instead immediately dereference it and copy the object.

Comment: and : when do you think this loop will end ? `for(i = length; length > 0; i--)`

Comment: note that C99 also has a built-in complex type

Comment: @pmg: "brand new" meaning "only 19 years old". And they say that technology *accelerates* changes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating memory for a new instance in `instanceOfComplex` and you return that (i.e. you return a pointer to the newly allocated memory).

In your `main` you dereference the pointer and assign the values to the array element.

You are loosing memory. Eiter allocate in `main` an array of pointers to complex, or have a local variable in `instanceOfComplex` that you return by value.

As user Yakov Dan says in his answer, you wrongly allocate the memory in `main` which probably causes your error.

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate memory for your array, it's wrong to say `sizeof(length+1)`.

Instead, that line should be:

```
struct Complex* complexArray = malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(struct Complex));
```